# How can I copy pyre2.Pattern object

Tags: python, re2

I am using pyre2 in my code and get such error:

```
>>> import re2
>>> pattern = re2.compile('gfhkjgf')
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> pattern_copy = deepcopy(pattern)
>>> pattern.match('hgjfkkhjg')
>>> pattern_copy.match('hgjfkkhjg')
[1]    21440 segmentation fault  python
```

Python version:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 15:04:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
```

This is simplified example of what I am trying to do.
In my code I have `Config` object which is looking like `{re2.Pattern: str}` in some cases I need to update it with value and pass to some function.

Why I cannot just copy `re2.Pattern` object?

UPD: With re everything is ok

Comment: why are you `deepcopy`ing pattern?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov if your question is "why are you not using copy instead of deepcopy?" then it's because copy is not working too

Comment: nope, my question is about why do you need a copy of a pattern in the first place?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I use dict {pattern: string} as config in my application. In some cases I have to add some patterns to initial config but if I just update config, new version will be using to the next config reload, so I want to create new variable with copy of initial config. Now I solved it with creating variable on config load step. But I'm still intersting in causes of this issue